# Issue with WPF custom control (Multi-Select Combobox)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

On code project I found the following:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MultiComboBox.aspx

I have integrated the following into a sample application and it seems to be working well.  The only issue I have right now is that if I type in the control I would like to be taken to the items that start with those letters the same way a normal combobox or listbox functions.

I have tried adding `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"` and `TextSearch.TextPath="City"` as well as `IsTextSearchEnabled="True"`.

None of these seem to be helping.  Any thoughts on how to implement text search functionality using this control?

Comment: if it can only be done in code behind then yes.  Either language would be fine I could convert if necessary.  If it can be done purely in XAML, even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author confirm that the control is build to mimic a `ComboBox`, but it isn't: you should implement your own custom logic to the automatic selection.

EDIT (a.k.a. even better than a finger in the eye)

With reference to the original code:
1) In the Generic.xaml search the `MultiSelectComboBoxReadOnlyTemplate`, then look for the `ScrollViewer` tag: name it as "PART_Scroller".

2) Open the MultiComboBox.cs module then find the OnKeyDown function. Modify as follows:

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
        {
            IsDropDownOpen = !IsDropDownOpen;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (IsDropDownOpen)
        {
            if (e.Key>=Key.A && e.Key<= Key.Z) //make it better!
            {
                var ch = (char)((int)(e.Key-Key.A) + 0x41); //awful!!!
                for (int i = 0, count = this.Items.Count; i < count; i++)
                {
                    var text = string.Format("{0}", this.Items[i]);
                    if (text.StartsWith(new string(ch, 1)))
                    {
                        ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                        var scroller = (ScrollViewer)this.GetTemplateChild("PART_Scroller"); //move out in OnApplyTemplate
                        scroller.ScrollToVerticalOffset(i);
                        this.ScrollIntoView(listBoxItem);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
```

You should make the key analysis better than the mine, but the road is pretty sunny.
NOTE: I didn't tried so much to test, I guess should be OK, at least to give you an help.
Cheers
Mario

EDIT2: here is how to keeping track of the key pressed within one second.
1) Modify as follows:

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
        {
            IsDropDownOpen = !IsDropDownOpen;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (IsDropDownOpen)
        {
            if (e.Key>=Key.A && e.Key<= Key.Z) //make it better!
            {
                var ch = (char)((int)(e.Key-Key.A) + 0x41); //awful!!!
                this._textSought += ch;
                this._timer.Stop();
                this._timer.Start();

                for (int i = 0, count = this.Items.Count; i < count; i++)
                {
                    var text = string.Format("{0}", this.Items[i]);
                    if (text.StartsWith(this._textSought, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                        var scroller = (ScrollViewer)this.GetTemplateChild("PART_Scroller"); //move out in OnApplyTemplate
                        scroller.ScrollToVerticalOffset(i);
                        this.ScrollIntoView(listBoxItem);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
```

2) add the following to the same class:

```
    public MultiComboBox()
    {
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MultiComboBox_Loaded);
        this.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MultiComboBox_Unloaded);
    }

    void MultiComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        this._timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        this._timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
    }

    void MultiComboBox_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this._timer != null)
        {
            this._timer.Stop();
            this._timer = null;
        }
    }

    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this._timer.Stop();
        this._textSought = string.Empty;
    }

    private DispatcherTimer _timer;
    private string _textSought = string.Empty;
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers
Mario

Comment: That is exactly what I am stuck on... hence, the question

Comment: Let me understand well: once the list drops down, you would to press a key, so that the list scrolls toward the nearest item beginning with that letter? Or either you're asking for a more-funky combo, that filters (then shows you)  only the items containing that letter?

Comment: Press a key and scroll the list to nearest beginning with that letter

Comment: This worked well thanks!  Is it possible for this to search for more than one character in length?  Since, the event is OnKeyDown, I'm not quite sure what the best implementation of that would be, but any thoughts?